# Search/replace variable text in database

Tags: mysql, regex, sed

I need to replace some text in a database column.
example: replace `[youtube]zWg85ALiCUY[/youtube]` with `//youtube.com/watch?v=zWg85ALiCUY`

How do I do it properly?

I've tried dumping the database and running the following command.

```
sed -i -E "s/\[youtube\](.+)\[\/youtube]/https:\/\/www\.youtube\.com\/watch\?v=\1/" dump.sql
```

it didn't replace all instances properly.
Any other better way? I'm not particularly good with regExp.

**Update:** 
Some of the posts have multiple [youtube] BBCode in it.

```
[youtube]zWg85ALiCUY[/youtube] some text... [youtube]huawda5hy[/youtube]
```

Each of them needs to be updated.

Comment: To begin, don't work on the dump, use your favourite language to send a query that selects interesting columns only.

Comment: I suggest to replace `.+` with `[^[]+` and `/"` with `/g"`.

Comment: Any idea, how to deal with posts that has two or more [youtube] bbcode in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in pure MySQL code and without using REGEX.

**Query**

```
SELECT 
 REPLACE(REPLACE(col, '[youtube]', '//youtube.com/watch?v='), '[/youtube]', '')
FROM (
  SELECT '[youtube]zWg85ALiCUY[/youtube]' AS `col`
) 
 records
```

**Result**

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(col, '[youtube]', '//youtube.com/watch?v='), '[/youtube]', '')  
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//youtube.com/watch?v=zWg85ALiCUY
```

Comment: It's a good idea in theory, but nothing proves that the bbcode tags are correctly closed in practice.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, What to do if some posts have two or more [youtube] bbcodes in it?

Comment: @DtyCFx The function REPLACE will replace all the matches in a string check out http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d3ba84/3

Answer (score 0):

Run the following against the database:

> ```
> update table
> set column_name = replace(column_name, '[youtube]zWg85ALiCUY[/youtube]', '//youtube.com/watch?v=zWg85ALiCUY')
> ```

Comment: zWg85ALiCUY is obviously variable and there are thousands of posts to replace.